# Unexpected call to a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm not really good at JavaScript so I'm here asking.

Below is a sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function test(one)
{
alert('surprise! first function with one parameter');
}

function test(one,two)
{
alert('expected: second function with two parameters');
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:test('first')">
</body>
</html>
```

Questions:

I expected that that `'surprise! first function with one parameter'` would be then alerted `onload` because I call the function with one parameter only. To my surprise it alerted in the second function.

- Can someone explain this to me why?
- and how can I make my way around it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript doesn't support method overloading;
It just overwrites the function so the last one will get called every time.

A way around it is just to make 1 function and put some conditions in there to check if the variables are set.

Answer (score 2):

You declare twice the function test. The 2nd one overwrite the first definition.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript overloaded functions are not allowed. so in this case the second function overrides the first one and therefore you always see this result.

A work around for this is to check the values of the parameters:

`function test(one,two)

{

if(two)

alert('expected: second function with two parameters');

else 

 alert('surprise! first function with one parameter');

}`

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the parameters for a function aren't required. You'd want to check to see if the parameter is undefined before using it.

If used this before in order to implement getter/setter type functionality in javascript similar to below:

```
var _pageSize;

function pageSize(value) {
    if (value) {
       _pageSize = value;
    }
    else {
       return _pageSize;
    }
}
```

You can then use the pageSize method to both get and set the page size like below:

```
if (pageSize() < 15) {
    pageSize(15)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Javascript doesn't do polymorphism like that. It does have an arguments collection that you can look in and then do the right thing  given the inputs..

stuff like:

```
function calcAverage() 
{ 
   var sum = 0 
   for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) 
      sum = sum + arguments[i] 
   var average = sum/arguments.length 
   return average 
} 
document.write("Average = " + calcAverage(400, 600, 83))
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling such function:

```
function test(one,two)
```

With only one parameter, the argument "two" will have special type: undefined.
Any attempt to access the variable two will fail with "two is undefined" error, to avoid such error use the typeof command:

```
function test(one,two)
{
   if (typeof two == "undefined") {
      //give default value
      two = "default value here";
   }
   ...
}
```